# Combine 7 images into one, one on top of each other and output as single image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried aligning all images on top of each other, it worked but because it was position:absolute; the final result was floating all around page. (It's in my other question I asked today on SO)
So I am thinking alternative ways,
I have a web page which dynamically loads images like this:

```
<div id="AvatarImgFrame">
<img src="http://chaterix.com/public/images/char_elements/base_dark.png">
<img src="http://chaterix.com/public/images/char_elements/eyes/blue.png">
<img src="http://chaterix.com/public/images/char_elements/hair/blond.png">
<img src="http://chaterix.com/public/images/char_elements/mouth/happy.png">
<img src="http://chaterix.com/public/images/char_elements/pants/patrick.png"><img src="http://chaterix.com/public/images/char_elements/shoes/bleu2.png">
<img src="http://chaterix.com/public/images/char_elements/torso/google.png"></div>
```

I am wondering - is it possible to use JavaScript (like PHP GD) to combine all 7 images into one image and output on page using javascript?

So say instead of printing out the above code, it would do something like this:

```
<div id="AvatarImgFrame">
<img src="http://chaterix.com/public/tempGenerated/character.png">
</div>
```

Is this possible? I am just sick of position absolute and stuff floating around, so if JS could combine 7 images and make it as 1 that would fix the problem.

Comment: Why don't you just use photoshop to combine them then use it. It seems that's what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Huangism that's not the point, images are dynamically loaded as there is about 1500 variations of how they can be put together.

Comment: @arleitiss then put that detail in the question, you can edit the question and add it in

Comment: @Huangism question was detailed, but nobody was able to asnwer, so I am looking for alternative solution.

Comment: @arleitiss I mean in this question, anyway, absolute positioning IS and SHOULD be used for this. You can post your broken code here, just create a very simple example on jsfiddle.net For now, make sure your absolute images are contained in a relative positioned container. So, #AccountAvatar should be positioned 'relative'. Also give the container a height because absolute positioned elements are out of the normal content flow

Comment: could also point image `src` at a php url that does the combining

Comment: @Huangism I am creating JFiddle now example page, so maybe somebody knows how to position floating element

Comment: @arleitiss have you tried adding a height to the container (`#AccountAvatar`) like I mentioned in my last comment?

Comment: @Huangism yes, I added height: 500px; that didn't work.
Here I made JFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rwh3emp2/

Comment: @arleitiss You added the height to the `img` instead of the container http://jsfiddle.net/rwh3emp2/1/ I added `#AvatarImgFrame { height: 230px; }` at the bottom of the css. Please read comments more carefully

Comment: @Huangism worked like a charm, thank you very much, wasted day trying to figure this out and it ended up small thing, I need to pay more attention. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This should be really simple with CSS and position absolute. I know you said you are looking for a different way, but this should be doable. Are you setting top, bottom, right and left position for the images? Don't forget that you need to add the px after the number. Also don't forget to set the position property on your parent element, or position absolute gets wonky.

Comment: You can check other question if you want, but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

if you use `position: absolute` correctly, things shouldn't be 'floating around the page'. Give the parent `position: relative` and they will be relative to this div. Give it a `top` and a `left` value, if you give it all 4 it will skew when you resize the page/div

Comment: You can check other question if you want, but it doesn't seem to work.